# Unexpected return value error in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2

Need help to resolve issue with return value in RxJava. So, here is what I have done so far:

```
private Observable<Boolean> updatedMenuItems() {
    return Observable.fromIterable(getAliases())
        .doOnNext(alias -> {
            return ApiRepository.getMenuItemBlocks(alias)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
                    .map(item -> item.getFileTimeStamp() == null ? "" : item.getFileTimeStamp().toString())
                    .toList()
                    .doOnSuccess(apiContents -> {
                        return Observable.fromCallable(DataStoreRepository::loadMenuItemsBlock)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
                                .map(item -> item.fileTimeStamp == null ? "" : item.fileTimeStamp.toString())
                                .toList()
                                .map(dbContents -> {
                                    return DBUtil.isContentEqual(dbContents, apiContents);
                                });
                    });

        });
}
```

I need to return `Observable<Boolean>` data type from this method but inside the block of `.doOnSuccess(...);` I am getting an error concerning return value. Could you please, help me to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: `doOnNext` and `doOnSuccess` are observing the chain only (should be used for side effects only), which has `Consumer` arguments, with `void` return type.

Answer (score 1):

> doOnNext, doOnSuccess, doOnError, doOnCompleted

These are called Side-effect operators, they don't really affect the chain in anyway, they might be used as a logging mechanism for ex.

What you're looking for is probably `flatMap`, from the docs:

> FlatMap: Transforms the items emitted by an Observable into Observables, then flatten the emissions from those into a single Observable.

Comment: `onNext`, `onSuccess`, `onError`, `onCompleted` - These are Subscriber events.  In this case I think you want to prefix these with "do"

Comment: thanks for your help, still looking for solution with return value issue

Comment: @MarkKeen yeah you're right!, will edit that.
surik I just told you, use flatMap